# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frontend' in python behave

Tags: python, python-behave

Hi I just setup new project here is the structure [image]

I got No module named 'frontend' when running from command line by 'behave' command
what is the way to fix this issue?

I added python to the system path during the python installation

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: If you are probably running Behave in command line writing:  behave frontend/features, 

then your working directory (where the script runs) will be frontend/features

What I usually do, is add to environment.py a line for adding the project root folder to sys.path:  sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..')))

Comment: @Monica Voinescu thanks I will try that but where exactly in env.py before all?

Comment: Before importing your frontend module, or any other module in the project path